# How to alert the value of textbox

Tags: javascript

I am trying to alert the value one of textbox of form in JavaScript but its not working and my other forms have same code of JavaScript they are working fine. I have spent lot of time to fix this issue but not succeed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        function call(){
            var siv=document.getElementById("siv")‌​.value;
            alert(siv);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form  name="alm" action="#" method="post" onSubmit="call();">
            <label>Province: </label><br>
            <select name="ProvinceDropDown" id="ProvinceDropDown">
                <option value="SelectProvince"> Please Select </option>
                <option value="Sindh" selected='selected'> Sindh </option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" value=""  id="siv" name="siv">
            <input type="submit" value="submit" >
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly does happen? Is there an error or does the script simply do nothing?

Comment: What does alert show? Undefined?

Comment: JS statement has some special characters. Just try `var siv=document.getElementById("siv")‌​.value;` instead of existing statement..[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/fxtxhvhu/)

Comment: If you are using strict mode, your variable name cannot be the same as id. From my experience tho.

Comment: these bugs can be solved by simply analyzing step by step

Answer (score 2):

You had some uncommon characters in your `var siv = document.getElementById("siv").value;` statement (which couldn't be seen unless your editor notifies you about them). Write it again (to remove those uncommon characters) and your code will work.

```js
function call() {
  var siv = document.getElementById("siv").value;
  alert(siv);
}
```

```html
<form name="alm" action="#" method="post" onSubmit="call();">
  <label>Province:</label>
  <br>
  <select name="ProvinceDropDown" id="ProvinceDropDown">
    <option value="SelectProvince">Please Select</option>
    <option value="Sindh" selected='selected'>Sindh</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" value="" id="siv" name="siv">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

check document.getElementById("id").value; spelling.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Your JavaScript code has \u200b (Zero width space)

[image]

Updated Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Stack Sample</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function call() {
  var siv = document.getElementById("siv").value;
  alert(siv);
}
</script>
<body>
    <form name="alm" action="#" method="post" onSubmit="call();">
  <label>Province:</label>
  <br>
  <select name="ProvinceDropDown" id="ProvinceDropDown">
    <option value="SelectProvince">Please Select</option>
    <option value="Sindh" selected='selected'>Sindh</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" value="" id="siv" name="siv">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```